# ng-repeat model.array[0].otherArray

Tags: angularjs

This questions is in relation to another question of mine; [angularjs-multi-level-tables-inside-another-if-clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544048/angularjs-multi-level-tables-inside-another-if-clicked). (You can see "full" JSON there.)

Why can't I have an ng-repeat like below?

```
<tbody>
<tr data-ng-repeat="dayData in storeDataModel.storedata[0].data">
  <td>{{dayData.date}}</td>
  <td>{{dayData.cost}}</td>
  <td>{{dayData.sales}}</td>
  <td>{{dayData.revenue}}</td>
  <td>{{dayData.employees}}</td>
  <td>{{dayData.employeeHoursSum}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Angular finds the number of objects in the array "dayData" for this particlar "store" (the storedata[0] is the first store) but for some reason it creates n+1 rows instead of n and there's no data at all in any of the rows.

I have also tried a lot of combinations, trying to make it work...:

- storeDataModel.storedata.data -returns no rows at all
- storeDataModel.storedata.$index.data -returns no rows at all
- storeDataModel.storedata.$index+1.data -returns errors
- storeDataModel.storedata.$first.data -returns no rows at all

> Is what I am trying to do possible at all or do I need to write a directive to get the specific store dayData information and put in a temporary model for that specific store and then do a ng-repeat on the temporary model?

(Also, as I am trying to get this particular table as content to a "fake accordion", i.e. when clicking a row in the parent table to expand/collapse and show this particular table (see my linked question) - are there any non-compatibilities if I include ng-clicked or own directive together with your proposed solution?)

Comment: strange it may be a bug,did you ask on google groups?

Comment: No. I have only posted it here. So it is supposed work to with an array index and then traverse further down? (dayData in storeDataModel.storedata[anyNumberWithinLimitsOfArray].data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ng-repeat, you have to iterate over an array. In your JSON, "data" is an object :

```
{
  "data": {
     ...
     "dayData" : [
       ...
     ]
   }
 }
```

So, you have to iterate over "dayData" :

```
<tbody>
<tr data-ng-repeat="dayData in storeDataModel.storedata[0].data.dayData">
  <td>{{dayData.date}}</td>
  <td>{{dayData.cost}}</td>
  <td>{{dayData.sales}}</td>
  <td>{{dayData.revenue}}</td>
  <td>{{dayData.employees}}</td>
  <td>{{dayData.employeeHoursSum}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

You can see it on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bcaudan/4yfyc/)

Comment: Oh, can't believe I missed that. I know that I have to ng-repeat over an array, just that I missed dayData in the end. Thanks.